# Integrating over a Truncated Elliptic Cone

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume, substitution, cylindrical-coordinates

So let's say that we have I can only describe as a "truncated elliptic cone" (TEC) as on the picture:

[image]

Let's further say that this TEC is of height $h$, and let's say that it is centered at the origin, such that the origin is a midpoint of the TEC's height and the midpoint of the central cross-section. It goes without saying that we've picked our coordinate system such that the the $a$'s in the picture extend along the $x$-axis, the $b$'s extend along the $y$-axis, and the height along the $z$-axis. Let's further say that we have another point somewhere in space at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, and we wish to evaluate the integral
$$
\int \int \int_{\text{TEC}} ((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2) dx dy dz .
$$
If $a_1=b_1=r_1$ and $a_2=b_2=r_2$ (i.e. we're just looking at a truncated cone), the task becomes rather easy. Changing coordinates to cylindrical ones, the equation becomes
$$
\int^{h/2}_{-h/2} \int^{2 \pi}_{0} \int^{\frac{1}{h} (r_2-r_1 + \frac{1}{2}(r_2-r_1))}_0 ( r^2 + r_0^2 - 2 r r_0 \cos[\phi - \phi_0] + (z - z_0)^2) r dr d \phi dz
$$
which good old Lady Mathematica tells us is
$$
\frac{1}{60} h \pi [20 r_0^2 (r_1^2 + r_1 r_2 + r_2^2) + 
   h^2 (2 r_1^2 + r_1 r_2 + 2 r_2^2) + 
   6 (r_1^4 + r_1^3 r_2 + r_1^2 r_2^2 + r_1 r_2^3 + r_2^4) + 
   10 h (r_1 - r2) (r_1 + r_2) z_0 + 20 (r_1^2 + r_1 r_2 + r_2^2) z_0^2] .
$$
A long and cumbersome expression, perhaps, but impeccable for my purposes.

However, when I try to solve the general case using cylindrical coordinates, I end up with integrands that are so complicated that not even Lady Mathematica can integrate them.

As such, I am asking you if anyone of you perhaps can come up with some neat coordinate substitution or other trick that would allow me to evaluate this integral?

Looking forward to your responses!

Comment: Is this the right equation for the TEC?

$$\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac{(\text{a2}-\text{a1}) \left(\frac{h}{2}+z\right)}{h}+\text{a1}\right)^2}+\frac{y^2}{\left(\frac{(\text{b2}-\text{b1}) \left(\frac{h}{2}+z\right)}{h}+\text{b1}\right)^2}=1$$

Comment: Depends on what you mean. The equation provided does give the boundary of the TEC as you go from the bottom to the top if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the functions:

$$
a(z) := \underbrace{\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}}_{\alpha_1} - \underbrace{\frac{a_1-a_2}{2}}_{\alpha_2}\frac{2\,z}{h},
\quad \quad
b(z) := \underbrace{\frac{b_1+b_2}{2}}_{\beta_1} - \underbrace{\frac{b_1-b_2}{2}}_{\beta_2}\frac{2\,z}{h}
$$

the *"generalized" truncated elliptic cone* is:

$$
\Omega := \left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \frac{x^2}{a(z)^2} + \frac{y^2}{b(z)^2} \le 1, \, -\frac{h}{2} \le z \le \frac{h}{2}\right\}
$$

where the *"classic" truncated elliptic cone* is obtained if $a_2/a_1 = b_2/b_1$, i.e. $\alpha_2/\alpha_1 = \beta_2/\beta_1$.

So, through a *transformation of coordinates* of the type:

$$
\begin{cases}
\color{red}{x} = a(\color{blue}{z})\,\rho\cos\theta \\
\color{green}{y} = b(\color{blue}{z})\,\rho\sin\theta \\
\color{blue}{z} = \frac{h}{2}\,t \\
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \text{with} \;
(\rho,\theta,t) \in [0,1] \times [0,2\pi) \times \left[-1,1\right]
$$

the following triple integral is easy to calculate:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I 
& := \iiint\limits_{\Omega} \left((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2\right)\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z \\
& = \int_{-1}^1 \text{d}t \int_0^{2\pi} \text{d}\theta \int_0^1 \left((\color{red}{x}-x_0)^2+(\color{green}{y}-y_0)^2+(\color{blue}{z}-z_0)^2\right)a(\color{blue}{z})\,b(\color{blue}{z})\,\frac{h}{2}\,\rho\,\text{d}\rho \\
& = \boxed{\frac{\pi\,h}{60}\left[15\alpha_1\beta_1\left(\alpha_1^2+\beta_1^2\right)+3\alpha_2\beta_2\left(\alpha_2^2+\beta_2^2\right)+5\left(\alpha_1\beta_2+\alpha_2\beta_1\right)\left(3\alpha_1\alpha_2+3\beta_1\beta_2\;\\+4\,h\,z_0\right)+\left(5\alpha_1\beta_1+3\alpha_2\beta_2\right)h^2+20\left(3\alpha_1\beta_1+\alpha_2\beta_2\right)\left(x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2\right)\right].} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Quite marvellous, thank you very much! :D

Comment: Well, that's far more than I asked for, but I certainly won't complain when they give you a free dessert on top of a free meal! :)

Comment: Yes, I feel the need to make the quick comment that there is a slight discrepancy between my drawing and TeM's wonderful computations here. I had $a_1, a_2,b_1,b_2$ be twice the semi-major and semi-minor axes, wheres in TeM's computations (which are more in line with how these should be written in the literature, and as such to be preferred) $a_1, a_2,b_1,b_2$ are in fact the semi-major and semi-minor axes. Something you want to watch out for in case you wish to use this result.